# Codename One iPhone 11 install issue

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

I have a codename one program that I ran on my iPhone 7.  That phone recently died and I got an iPhone11 pro.  I deleted the UDID from the old phone and added the new phones UDID into my apple developer account.  I generated a new build (debug build) which built with no issues but when I try to install on my iPhone it fails and the icon has the title ProgramName,ProgramName instead of just ProgramName.  When I press the icon it says "Unable to Install "ProgramName,ProgramName" Please try again later".  I suspect this is why it failed since it won't match what I have in my apple developer (Identifier Name: ProgramName).  I tried adding my UDID for my iPad and tried installing the program but I get the same issue.

The last time I installed the program on my old iPhone was about 2 months ago.  The other people who use the program all have android phones which as recently as last week installed with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is the checklist you need to go over: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/my-ios-build-wont-install.html

Since both devices are 64 bit I'm guessing that wouldn't have been the problem but did you download the edited provisioning profile file to replace the existing one?

Notice that the provisioning profile used is the one you have on your machine this isn't pulled from your Apple account.